# RSA to send messages that are integers less than or equal to B = 10^6

Tags: number-theory

We want to use RSA to send messages that are integers less than or equal to B = 10^6

Find two primes $p$ and $q$ that could be used for key-generation. Choose your primes in such a way that:

$$\sqrt{B} + \sqrt[3]{B} \leq q < \sqrt{B} + 5 \sqrt[3]{B} \\ \sqrt{B} - 5 \sqrt[3]{B} \leq p < \sqrt{B} - \sqrt[3]{B}$$

Explain in detail how you generated $p$ and $q$. To generate a random prime in the interval $[u,v]$, you can use the SAGE command: random_prime($v$, $\, $lbound=$u$)

Comment: Aside from the title, this is word-for-word identical with your question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557357/find-two-primes-p-and-q-that-could-be-used-for-key-generation). It was closed because it's missing context and details; please add these.

Comment: I did.  The last was missing B = 10^6

Comment: There is no other part of the instructions i left out

Comment: No, it doesn't say anything like that

Comment: @Miller.Steve: Did my solution resolve your issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we substitute $B$ into the two expressions, we get the following ranges for the prime numbers:

$$1100 \lt p \lt 1500$$

$$500 \lt q \lt 900$$

By the way, the equality statements do not make sense for the given value of $B$ as you can clearly see. Different values of $B$ could give a lower range that is a prime however.

So, now we need some method to choose a random prime number in each of these ranges.

Your problem refers to SAGE, so use that for your implementation.

Here is an example (I use Mathematica's $\color{red} {RandomPrime[{1100,1500}]}$, for example, to choose the random prime and you should validate that it is a prime using some method like Miller-Rabin or better which you have likely learned).

$$p = 1373, q = 877$$

Note that since we want to encrypt numbers that are as large as $10^6$, we need for $n = pq$ to be at least that large.

If you want, here are the other calculations (these are not unique of course):

- $n = pq = 1204121$
- $e = 1045525$ (Encryption exponent)
- $d = 433597$ (Decryption exponent)

If we want to encrypt a message, say $m = 999$, we get:

- Ciphertext = $c = m^e \pmod n = 999^{650387} \pmod {662903} = 1182759$
- Plaintext = $p = c^d \pmod n = 650880^{608123} \pmod {662903} = 999$

Comment: Yes, thank you. But don't you mean:

Comment: I am confused, don't I mean?

Comment: 999^1045525(mod1204121)= 1182759  and 1182769^433597(mod1204121)=999? How did you solve for D? I know that it's 1045525(D)=1(mod1201872) where 1201872 is the phi of n. @Amzoti

Comment: NM I got it. I used SAGE inverse_mod(e, phi N)